# Getting docker error, daemon is missing signature key on docker pull

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry, jfrog-container-registry, docker-daemon

I have been trying to pull a docker image; which has been pushed successfully to the private jfrog repository using the same terminal and in same session. There comes no issues while pushing the image, however on doing a pull it is getting failed with the following region.

```
[xxxx@xxxx~]$ sudo docker pull  docker-repo/xxxx-xxxx-xxx/xx/tomcat-xx:latest
Error response from daemon: missing signature key
```

If anyone can help what could be reason for this? The difference I can see wrt to the image I pushed through this terminal and the images which are already present in jfrog repo is that manifest has cetain properties associated with them. However, there are no properties present in jfrog repo wrt to image I pushed from this terminal.

Following are the details for reference:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:25:41 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:24:18 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Is there anything I am missing at configuration end. Kindly help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more details? 
How is this JCR setup? Saas or your own? If own, how did you set it up?
Does it happen to any Docker image you push it or just one?

Answer (score 5):

The error message suggests that it's something wrong on the client side. In my case it was my docker version being too old. I upgraded it and the error was gone.

In fact, my OS version was too old so I had to upgrade it (Debian 9 -> 10), the newer version of OS had the newer version of docker.

Comment: Hello, do you have details on what was too old? What component was outdated so that was creating this issue?

Comment: Now everything works with docker-ce 24.0.6, unfortunately I can't find a way to get the version I had before upgrading. This happens on Debian Buster (10).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with JFrog Artifactory. For me, it helped to give `annotate` permissions to the user pushing the image, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979841).

Comment: Yes you are right. Giving annotate permission solved my problem.